# JavaScript Switch statement: checking 2 cases at a time

Tags: javascript, if-statement, switch-statement

I am a bit confused with the switch statement, i need it for my home page. I'll explain shortly: i have two groups of radio buttons on my html code, each consisting of three buttons. According to the button selected an image will be shown (means three different images for one group and three different for the other). There are shown also two images at a time. This works with my code so far. What I would like to do next is to show a third image according to the combination of buttons chosen. This is my code so far

```
    <html>
<head>
<title>Radio-Buttons</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Testing</h1>

<script language='JavaScript' type='text/javascript'>


    function check_value(fieldvalue)
    {    

        switch(fieldvalue)
        {
            case 1:

                document.getElementById("imagedest").innerHTML = "<img src='image1.jpg'>";

                    break;

            case 2:

                document.getElementById("imagedest").innerHTML = "<img src='image2.png'>"; 

                    break;

            case 3:

                document.getElementById("imagedest").innerHTML = "<img src='image3.jpg'>"; 

                    break;
        }

   }
    function check_other_value(fieldvalue)
    {   

        switch(fieldvalue)
        {
            case 1:

                document.getElementById("imagedest2").innerHTML = "<img src='image4.jpg'>";



            break;

            case 2:

                document.getElementById("imagedest2").innerHTML = "<img src='image5.png'>";


        break;

            case 3:

                document.getElementById("imagedest3").innerHTML = "<img src='image6.jpg'>";

    }

    }


</script>

<form name='test'>
    <input type="radio" name="field" value="one" onclick='check_value(1)'>one 
    <input type="radio" name="field" value="two" onclick='check_value(2)'>two 
    <input type="radio" name="field" value="three" onclick='check_value(3)'>three 
</form>

<div id='imagedest'>
</div>


<form name='tests'>
    <input type="radio" name="fields" value="one" onclick='check_other_value(1)'>one 
    <input type="radio" name="fields" value="two" onclick='check_other_value(2)'>two 
    <input type="radio" name="fields" value="three" onclick='check_other_value(3)'>three 
</form>

<div id='imagedest2'>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

This code works for what i descrived previously. I thought on using an "if" statement to check the first case selected, but as far as i understand, after the "breaks" the function "erases" everything and starts from 0.

Can anybody give me an idea on how to make it work?

Thank you,
Jordi

Comment: I'm sorry for my code shown before,

Comment: @ user: You can fix it. Click "edit" and then look at the handy **How to Format** box to the right when you're editing, and the preview underneath. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass both values to a third function and do whatever checks you need to do there.

```
function check_third_value( field1, field2 )
{
    if( field1 == 1 && field2 == 2 ) {
        // do something
    } else if( field1 == 2 && field2 == 2 ) {
        // do something else
    } else if...
}
```

How you pass the values depends on how you trigger the changes. You can also get the values with `document.getElementById("fieldID").value`, depending on your HTML.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. You seem to have understood what I want to do, what is unclear for me right now is what do you mean with passing the values. on field1 i'd have to save the results of one switch statement and on field2 the results of the other switch statement. How can I do this? I've tried declearing variables in each funtion and assigning a value to the variables in each case, but it seems like they are erased after the cases

Comment: Just forget the earlier switch statements. What I was trying to imply is that if you showed the full HTML you have, it'd be easier to show a complete example of how to accomplish what you want.

Comment: ok I'll post it in another thread and paste the link to that thread here, just a minute

Comment: fantastic than you very much

Answer (score 0):

Call me simple, but why don't you just do it like this:

```
function updateImage(value_1, value_2) {
    document.getElementById("image_1").innerHTML = '<img src="img_1_' + value_1 + 'jpg">';
    document.getElementById("image_2").innerHTML = '<img src="img_2_' + value_2 + 'jpg">';
    document.getElementById("image_3").innerHTML = '<img src="img_3_' + value_1 + '_' + value_2 + 'jpg">';
}
```